# ChromiumHeadless stderr: /system.slice/bamboo-agent.service is not a snap cgroup

Tags: snap, chromium

I have Atlassian Bamboo agent running as a service on Ubuntu and part of the build process for our product uses headless Chromium to test UI development.  Prior to Ubuntu 20.04, this was no problem.  Once snap got involved, it was a headache to get the agents building again.  I effectively had to do some trickery by creating a symlink to emulate a directory it required.

I recently upgraded one of the VMs to Ubuntu 22.04 and I having issues once again getting the agent to use Chromium managed by snap.  I receive the below error.

ChromiumHeadless stderr: /system.slice/bamboo-agent.service is not a snap cgroup

How can I grant the bamboo-agent.service permission to use Chromium?  If there is a way for me to install Chromium without snap, that would be better.